# Standard Colors for Landcover Maps

Tags: grass-gis, standards, color, classification, colortable

I have classified Landsat images into five classes - A variety of Palm, Water bodies, built-up/open area, other vegetation and miscellaneous. I used GRASS GIS for the process and the final classified maps use inappropriate colors. Now as I have to assign appropriate colors to these classes I was thinking about existence of internationally accepted standards for such purposes.

As palm which covers only 10% of total area is the class of my interest(shown in yellow in the following screenshot) I want it to be clearly distinguishable in my A4 size paper output. In the most unlikely event of absence of standards proper color suggestions are greatly welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the standard ndvi color table in GRASS. Right click on the layer and choose SET COLORTABLE.

However your question is a tautology. You have pointed out that you are the only one interested in Palm. A standard colour table would have been designed to make something else the most easily distinguishable feature. In the case of the ndvi color ramp it provides a scale of increasing density of vegetative response, not really providing any classification as such.

The help file for the GRASS color table gives an explanation of each option.